# Loading .dta data into R takes long time

Tags: r

Some confidential data is stored on a server and accessible for researchers via remote access.

- Researchers can login via some (I think cisco) remote client, and share virtual machines on the same host
- There's a 64 bit Windows running on the virtual machine

The system appears to be optimized for Stata, I'm among the first to use the data using R. There is no `RStudio` installed on the client, just the `RGui 3.0.2`.

And here's my problem: the data is saved in the stata format (`.dta`), and I need to open it in `R`. At the moment I am doing

```
read.dta(fileName, convert.factors = FALSE)[fields]
```

Loading in a smaller file (around 200MB) takes 1-2 minutes. However, loading in the main file (3-4 GB) takes very long, longer than my patience was for me. During that time, the R GUI is not responding anymore.

I can test my code on my own machine (OS X, RStudio) on a smaller data sample, which works all fine. Is this

- because of OS X + RStudio, or only
- because of the size of the file?

A college is using `Stata` on a similar file in their environment, and that was working fine for him.

What can I do to improve the situation? Possible solutions I came up with were

- Load the data into `R` somehow differently (perhaps there is a way that doesn't require all this memory usage). I have also access to stata. If all else fails, I could prepare the data in Stata, for example slice it into smaller pieces and reassemble it in `R`
- Ask them to allocate more memory to my user of the VM (if that indeed is the issue)
- Ask them to provide RStudio as a backend (even if that's not faster, perhaps its less prone to crashes)

Comment: Have you tried `haven` package?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I will check whether it turns out to be faster on my small data sample. Is there a way to generate artificial large stata data, just to compare loading times?

Comment: yes, take a small example 200MB and then aggregate it multiple times up to 2GB-3GB to see how the loading time evolves.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the size of the file is a prime factor, but the machine and configuration might be, too.  Hard to tell without more information.  You need a 64 bit operating system and a 64 bit version of R.

I don't imagine that RStudio will help or hinder the process.

*If* the process scales linearly, it means your big data case will take (120 seconds)*(4096 MB/200 MB) =2458 seconds, or around three quarters of an hour.  Is that how long you waited?

The process *might* not be linear.

Was the processor making progress?  If you checked CPU and memory, was the process still running?  Was it doing a lot of page swaps?

Comment: The process was still running, the application was not responding. The amount of RAM under use kept increasing, CPU usage was constant and positive. Absolute values of RAM and CPU were hard to interpret for me, given that they are apparently shared among other users